# Stacktrace information preserving paths of original source

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

I am using C#.net for application development.

To log and debug exceptions, I use the stacktrace.

I executed my application on another machine, but when errors occur it refers to the path of my development machine.

```
Ex:   D:\Projects\xyz.CS line no :12 _Error_message_here.
```

Why does it trace to the path on my *development* machine path even though I am running the application on another machine?

Answer (score 25):

The original compiled path is stored in the debug information within the PDB files.

Answer (score 16):

Because it's telling you where to find the problem in your *source code*. So when you see this, you can go to your machine and open the file reported (e.g. "D:\Projects\xyz.cs"), go to the reported line (e.g. 12) and fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation

When you do a Debug build, it includes source information in the compiled files to enable debugging, e.g. pause, step over, etc.

### Solution

If you don't want the source information to be included perform a Release build and deploy that to the other machine.